# Left click to download mp3

Tags: html, download, mp3

I have searched and can't find a solid answer to this question.

Is it possible to instead of right clicking and saving the file as... Can you instead code it to make it downloadable on left click and also keep it in .mp3 format?

Comment: You can force it to download if you use PHP (or ASP should also work I guess). Do you have something in the backend?

Comment: This is controlled by the browser, which browser do you want to use?

Comment: @TJD this is not necessarily controlled by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Set the [`Content-Disposition` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses) to `attachment` on the server side, when serving the mp3. Something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SloJamz.mp3"
```

---

The implementation specifics depend on what server-side language(s)/framework(s) you're using.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how your app/web server sends this data. in order to download a file directly it should be sent with a

```
"Content-Disposition:  "attachment"
```

header.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your .htaccess file

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp3
```